# Should the tags stellar-classification and spectral-type be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag

We have two tags, [spectral-type](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spectral-type) and [stellar-classification](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stellar-classification). The former appears to be slightly more popular, and the latter appears to have been mostly used on questions about spectral types?

Do we need both of these, and if we merge them what should the merged tag be?

**update:** in order to get to the bottom of this, there is a question in the main site where the technical issue can be resolved before the tagging issue is addressed.

- [Does "spectral type" and "stellar classification" refer to the same thing?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/40393/7982)

Comment: Following to see what others say.